# How do I properly use MongoDB for Strongloop scaffolded user model storage?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm new to Strongloop and newish to MongoDB. So many learning curves going on right now.

My basic issue is I switched the user model (models.json) datasource from the memory connector to the loopback-connector-mongodb connector and I no longer get a userId when I call /login. I get back an accesstoken, but the userID is null. If I switch back to the memory connector, I'll get a userId of 1 or whatever.

It seems like I remember reading somewhere if I do not supply an ID Strongloop would add one for me. Is this only for the in-memory datastore? Do I need to do something special since it's mongo?

Do I need to switch the accessToken model to mongo as well (I just thought of this)?

thanks.

Comment: What version are you on? We recently fixed a similar issue. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/353

Comment: My SL client is v2.5.5 (node v0.10.29).

Comment: Also my juggler is v1.6.3.

Comment: @RaymondFeng The final solution presented in the issue 353 link did not work for me (which was adding a relations to the accessToken model). I will note that other than switching the dataSource property I did not touch the models.json file from the default from the scaffold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit an edge case here: user and accessToken are backed by two different types of DBs. MongoDB uses ObjectID as the default key while memory DB uses number.

accessToken extends from base AccessToken. It inherits the belongsTo relation to base User model. The userId type is set to number. To fix the problem, you can either make sure accessToken model is connected to mongodb or add the following relation in models.json.

```
  "accessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true,
    "options": {
      "base": "AccessToken",
      "relations": {
        "user": {
          "model": "user",
          "type": "belongsTo",
          "foreignKey": "userId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: When I added the 'relations' from the issue link it had the foreignKey still set to 'ID'. Changing it to 'userId' got it working for me. I'm not sure I understand the edge case here. Switching the user model to a real datastore would seem a very common use case (I had switched accessToken to mongodb as well). Should the scaffold not add this belongsTo relationship? Seems like it would work with either memory or mongodb. Does it break an Oracle connector or something??  But that's another question ;-)  Thanks for the help!